# How to make BizTalk only take one message at a time from the MSMQ

Tags: biztalk, msmq

I have a BizTalk orchestration that is picking up messages from an MSMQ. It processes the message and sends it on to another system.

The thing is, whenever a message is put on the queue, BizTalk dequeues it immediately even if it is still processing the previous message. This is a real pain because if I restart the orchestration then all the unprocessed messages get deleted.

Is there any way to make BizTalk only take one message at a time, so that it completely finishes processing the message before taking the next one?

Sorry if this is an obvious question, I have inherited a BizTalk system and can't find the answer online.

Comment: Can you explain your pain point bit more? What do you mean by restart orchestration? Is it restart host instance? It should never cause any message loss. It seems like you want to introduce such processing due to some other underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are three properties of the BizTalk MSMQ adapter you could try to play around with:

**batchSize**

Specifies the number of messages that the adapter will take off the queue at a time. The default value is 20.

This may or may not help you. Even when set to 1, I suspect BTS will try to consume remaining "single" messages concurrently as it will always try parallel processing, but I may be wrong about that.

**serialProcessing**

Specifies messages are dequeued in the order they were enqueued. The default is false.

This is more likely to help because to guarantee ordered processing, you are fundamentally limited to single threaded processing. However, I'm not sure if this will be enough on its own, or whether it will only mediate the ordering of message delivery to the message box database. You may need to enable ordered delivery throughout the BTS application too, which can only be done at design time (i.e. require code changes).

**transactional**

Specifies that messages will be sent to the message box database as part of a DTC transaction. The default is false.

This will likely help with your other problem where messages are "getting lost". If the queue is non-transactional, and moreover, not enlisted in a larger transaction scope which reaches down to the message box DB, that will result in message loss if messages are dequeued but not processed. By making the whole process atomic, any messages which are not committed to the message box will be rolled back onto the queue.

Sources:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578644.aspx

Answer (score 0):

While you can process the messages in order by using Ordered Delivery, there is no way to serialize to they way you're asking.

However, merely stopping the Orchestration should not delete anything, much less 'all the unprocessed messages'.  Seems that's you problem.

You should be able to stop processing without losing anything.

If the Orchestration is going into a **Suspended** state, then all you need to do is **Resume** that one orchestration and any messages queued will remain and be processed.  This would be the default behavior even if the app was created 'correctly' by accident ;).

When you Stop the Application, you're actually Terminating the existing Orchestration and everything associated with it, including any queued messages.

Here's your potential problem, if the original developer didn't properly handle the Port error, the Orchestration might get stuck in an un-finishable Loop.  That would require a (very minor) mod to the Orchestration itself.

Comment: I suspect the code was badly written, but we are just supporting the application and we no longer have any skills to modify the code. Sometimes we get repeated failures (eg because the downstream system is not responding) and the Orchestration logs a message saying that it is suspended and we need to restart the Orchestration. When we do that, it starts working again but all the unprocessed messages that it had removed from the queue get deleted.

Comment: We do this by restarting the application. I've just looked and actually it seems we can restart just the orchestration? Should we be doing that instead?